# Arcsine for a value

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

I want to exactly determine the arcsine (sine inverse) for a value. Say I take $\sin$ for $60000$, which is approximately $-0.866$. I want to get back $60000$ from this. Taking a sine inverse will not work for obvious reasons. Is there a work around?

Comment: You might be interested in the complex logarithm form of your function:
$arcsin(x)=-i\ln(ix+\sqrt{1-x^2})$
Although I don't see why one should want to calculate by hand the inverse of the sinus function for non-exact values.

Comment: There's no real way: there are infinely many angles sharing the same sine.

Comment: Without more info $\sin(60000) = 0.95746675\dots$, so I guess you are working with degrees. One way is to (basically) decompose $60000 = 360 n + r,\;$ 
work with the principal branch $\arcsin r,\;$ and finally add back $360 n.$

Comment: The arcsine function is not injective, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) is [periodic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function), with a period of $2\pi$, so there are an infinity of real values *x* for which $\sin x=a$, for a given *a*. Also, $\sin x=\sin(\pi-x)$, so there are two values in each such interval of length $2\pi$.